# How can saved file on XP Home be accessible from Windows 7 Home

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, file-sharing

A client is using XP Home as their "MAIN" computer while the other two computers in her office are Windows 7 Home Premium.

The main document location is on the MAIN computer and is shared with full access to Everyone.

Documents created from either Win 7 Home system show up with ownership MAIN\Guest.

Documents created with "File"-"New" on the XP Home system show up with ownership MAIN\Nancy and are accessible.

BUT... documents saved from Yahoo attachments using IE 8 (I think) have ownership MAIN\Nance on \MAIN but are NOT accessible from the other systems. They are visible but show no owner information and attempts to open them produce an Access Denied message. [The documents are .xlsx spreadsheets created in Office 2007.]

If I propogate Everyone -> Full Control from the top of the shared My Documents on \MAIN the file becomes accessible but any newly saved ones have the same problem.

I would like to know how to set the sharings and permissions to prevent this but I am at a loss.

Comment: The problem is weirder than originally first specified. Simply saving attachments results in readable files. If the attachment is a .xlsx (Excel 2007) document and is OPENED in Excel 2003 an add-in converter runs. Saving back in .xlsx format also runs the reverse converter and then the permissions are wrong. If the file is saved in .xls format everything is fine. It is the add-in that is setting the permissions differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a workgroup you'll need to make identicial user names and passwords on each of the systems to get them to share files correctly and to get around the "access denied" message with out doing any additional work on your end.

[Here's the basic run down](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727037.aspx), writen specifically for Vista, but the concept is the same through XP - Win7

Comment: I do a LOT of Windows networking, generally in workgroups. Somehow the ability of the Guest login to access these files as changed. BUT... you are right. I need to setup the client with real logins and passwords that match on all three computers. I'm sure it will be fine after that. I was really looking for some help from the serverfault.com site from other administrators but they kicked this over to superuser. So it goes. :-)

Comment: I answered it while the question was still on SF. Your question at it's core is a permission issue, the best and most reliable way of fixing that is still with creating the same user accounts :)